# Expect returned value to equal $promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, karma-jasmine

I have this function that returns a `$promise`.

```
service.getPromise = () => {
    return myService.myFunction().$promise
};
```

and I have in my test code, I use karma and jasmine, the following.

```
it('should return a $promise', function () {
    expect(service.getPromise()).toEqual(???);
});
```

As you can see, I am not sure what to match or how to create a `$promise` so that I can test if what's returned actually is a `$promise`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
expect(service.getPromise() instanceof Promise).toBe(true);
```

edit: or if you're using angular's `$q` promises,

```
expect(service.getPromise() instanceof $q).toBe(true);
```

if all you care about is whether it returns a value of type promise. Alternatively you could check whether the returned object has the members you expect (e.g `then`)

Usually you would be more interested in what happens when the promise resolves though, I expect.

Comment: actually using `instanceof $q` worked but not `instanceof Promise`

Comment: Oh, good point, you're using angular of course. I've edited the answer.